# Python circular imports in class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, peewee

I have the following files:

#### user.py

```
...
from models.company import Company

class User(BaseModel):
    company = ForeignKeyField(Company, ...)
...
```

#### company.py

```
...
from models.user import User

class Company(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, ...)
...
```

This is a normal cyclic import error as far as python is concerned. The problem is that the usual workarounds (placing the import statement at the end of the file, importing in different ways, etc...) don't work in this context because I'm using one class in the definition of a class attribute of another class.

What is the proper way to solve the cyclic import error in this context?

Comment: Can you put them in 1 file and don't import at all?

Comment: Well, i have a lot of cases where that happens. It would be a massive "models" file. I don't think it's a good option

Comment: you can create an empty class and then import and reinstantiate the class, but I am pretty sure you should not need to do this kind of stuff

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by this?

Comment: That's a structural problem though...? What's the point of having `company.Company` and `user.User` instead of `models.objects.Company` and `models.objects.User`? So now within `objects` your `Company` and `User` would have reference to each other directly.

Comment: There are a lot of models. I wanted separated files for organization purposes. But if at the end of the day I need to do this, it will be done.

Comment: Note that you *can't* define both of these in the same file as they are written.  When you execute the first definition, it will fail because the name of the other class hasn't been defined yet, no matter which you define first.  What framework is `ForeignKeyField` from?  It may have tools for circumventing this.

Comment: It's from peewee ORM: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you are right, there is a `DeferredForeignKey` defined just for this. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Once you have a working solution, you should consider writing an answer to your own question, so others with this problem will know what to do.

Comment: At the risk of being yelled at, I think you should consider refactoring your domain model. Even though `DeferredForeignKey` exists, generally Circular Foreign Keys are bad for DB write transactions and don't really add much in query performance, in fact peewee does not actually create a real Foreign Key for a `DeferredForeignKey`. I think the DBA preference in this case would be separate non referential `User` and `Company` models with a `UserCompany` and/or `CompanyUser` table for references.

Comment: @tankthinks No one will yell at you on my watch . I understand your concern from the point of view of a DBA. But I'm not doing this for performance. I'm doing this for convenience on the ORM layer. The application is quite small and non-critical. There will be fewer than 2000 users.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Will do! ❤️️

Comment: To echo "tankthinks" comment, this schema is bogus and smelly. There's almost never a good reason for creating circular foreign-keys like this. Please don't do this in your code!

Comment: But what exactly is bad about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is in fact **impossible** as @PatrickHaugh pointed out:

> Note that you can't define both of these in the same file as they are written. When you execute the first definition, it will fail because the name of the other class hasn't been defined yet, no matter which you define first. What framework is ForeignKeyField from? It may have tools for circumventing this.

Since i'm using [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) as my ORM, there is a special field built for this pourpose: `DeferredForeignKey`.

So, at the end of the day, the solution was:

#### user.py

```
...
from models.company import Company

class User(BaseModel):
    company = ForeignKeyField(Company, ...)
...
```

#### company.py

```
...
class Company(BaseModel):
    user = DeferredForeignKey('User', ...)
...
```

Comment: Note that cyclical foreign-keys are considered a "smell" and discouraged in the peewee documentation.